# how to upload a file and process it with single button click in JSP

Tags: jsp

Previously in my UI, i had "Upload" button to upload the file to server after browsing the file. And then enter password in the password field and click on "Run" button to proceess the file. It was working fine.

Now the requirement changed as, no "Upload" button should be there. only "Run" button should be there.

Means, once after browsing the file and entering the password in "Password" field and click on the "Run" button, the file should get uploaded to the server first and then the file have to process as well.

I tried to move the 'upload()' function codes to 'run()' function, but it works only if there is a delay. like if there is a alert message then it works fine or else before file being uploaded the run button is trying to process the file and ends in error.
Tried Thread.sleep(5000); as well not working

```
/* function upload() {
        document.getElementById("messageDiv").innerHTML = "";  
        var file = window.document.forms[0].file.value;
        if (file == "") {
            alert("Select a file to upload!!");
        } else {
            window.document.forms[0].action = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/FileUpload.do?Action=Upload";
            window.document.forms[0].submit();
        }
    }*/

function runButton(){
        document.getElementById("messageDiv").innerHTML = "";
        var file = window.document.forms[0].file.value;
        if (file == "") {
            alert("Select a file to upload!!");
        } else {
            window.document.forms[0].action = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/FileUpload.do?Action=Upload";  //FileUploadServlet"; //
            window.document.forms[0].submit();
        }
        /* alert(" Upload Completed, Next runButton!! "); */ ** ---> if this is uncommented then works fine. **
        window.document.forms[0].action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/FileUpload.do?Action=Run";
            var passwd = window.document.forms[0].passwd.value;

            if (passwd == null || passwd == "") {
                alert(" Password cannot be empty!! ");
            } else {
                window.document.forms[0].submit();
                window.document.forms[0].passwd.value='';
            }
            document.getElementById("messageDiv").innerHTML = "";
    }
```

Suggestions pls

Comment: why don't you simply on click of submit button  do all processing ? or just use ajax to upload file then do further process ?

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion. I've completed it by having all the processes with "Upload" button itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've completed it by having all the processes with "Upload" button itself.